# discord.py How to send message after reacting to bot's message

Tags: python, discord.py

Hi guys i'm coding a Discord bot and i wanted to make a reaction game and the main thing is, if someone reacts the bot's message with this ✅ emoji, bot will send a message. Here is my code:

```
@client.command(aliases=['Game', 'GAME'])
async def game(ctx):
    emoji = '✅'
    message = await ctx.send("To start to game please react the message with :white_check_mark:!")
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `wait_for()` function. For reaction adding it would look like this:

```py
reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout = 30.0, check = check)
```

---

So, your command would look like this:

```py
@client.command(aliases=['Game', 'GAME'])
async def game(ctx):
    emoji = '✅'
    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author && str(reaction) == emoji

    message = await ctx.send("To start to game please react the message with :white_check_mark:!")
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)

    try:
        await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout = 30.0, check = check)
        await ctx.send('You can now start playing the game.')
    except:
        await message.delete()  # The message will be deleted if the user doesn't react with ✅ within 30 seconds
```

I hope now you get the idea on how to complete your game.